# creating a variable through a function?

Tags: python

Heres the idea:
I create a function that makes a variable, and stores some data inside of it, how would I do that?
e.g.:

```py
def create_variable(name, data):
    # code here

create_variable("x", "hello world!")
print(x)
# would return "hello world!"
```

something along those lines.

would anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Why would you do that?  Just return the value, and let the caller assign it to a variable if they want (or directly use the value in some other way, if they don't need it in a variable).

Comment: Right.  Don't do that.  You can do `x = create_variable(data)`.  If you really need dynamic variables, the Right Way is to use a dictionary.

Comment: I agree with Tim on using a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the variable value is only string (otherwise, you can add additional check and string parsing), you can use `exec` with `globals()` to run a string as python code to assign value to global variable.

```
def create_variable(name, data):
    # code here
    exec("{}='{}'".format(name, data), globals())

create_variable("x", "hello world!")
print(x)
```

Comment: Although this technically solves the problem, this is TERRIBLE coding practice.  Both the use of `exec` and the use of `globals()`  should be avoided except in very special circumstances.  This is not one.

Comment: Plus, if you're already using `globals`, you could just perform an ordinary dict item assignment instead of misusing `exec`.